# django not hashing password custom user

Tags: python, django

i am working on a model which inherits from from django.contrib.auth.models import **AbstractBaseUser**

earlier i was specifying **password** field like:

```
password = models.Charfield(max_length=150)
```

but then i need to specify it as:

```
create_password = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

in earlier case i was getting password in hashed format.
but after changing **password** to **create_password**
the value is saving in unhashed format (originally entered value).

all other settings are same as before, i am using user.set_password(create_password) function . but still no hashing.

how can i hash create_password field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set password function in Django `AbstractBaseUser` expects the password field name to be 'password' only, this is how the function looks if you go inside the `AbstractBaseUser` class:

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
    self.password = make_password(raw_password)
    self._password = raw_password
```

But if you for some reason need your password field to be create_password instead of 'password' you can override the 'set_password' function in your user model like this:

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
    self.create_password = make_password(raw_password)
    self._password = raw_password
```

I am assuming you have set your user model in the settings.py file and have created the Manager class as well.